# alternative to "onScroll" for hiding navbar?

Tags: javascript, navbar, hide, show

being new to scripting, I kindly request help with this issue:
I want my navbar (#header-menu) to be hidden when my homepage loads. After scrolling down a bit (500px), I want it to be to be shown. The script works, except for the fact that the navbar is shown when arriving to the homepage. It disappears when scrolling down and then appears again as it should. But the problem is that it is not hidden by default when arriving to the homepage (when clicking on the logo's, for example).

```
<header>
    <div id="header-content">
        <a href="index.php#toppage"><img src="images/Logo.png" alt="" style="float:left"></a>
        <a href="index.php#toppage"><img src="images/Logo2.png" alt="" style="float:right"></a>
    </div>

    <ul id="header-menu" class="grid-4">
        <li><a href="#menu-item-1" class="page-scroll menu-item-blue">menu-item-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu-item-2" class="page-scroll menu-item-blue">menu-item-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu-item-3" class="page-scroll menu-item-blue">menu-item-3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu-item-4" class="page-scroll menu-item-blue">menu-item-4</a></li>
</ul>
</header>
```

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {hidemenu()};
function hidemenu() {
var element = document.getElementById("header-menu");
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) {
    element.classList.remove("hidden");
  } else {
    element.classList.add("hidden");
  }
}
</script>
```

I guess in fact I am looking for an alternative to 'onscroll'. I don't want to trigger the hiding/showing of my navbar when the user scrolls, I want it to hide/show depending on the position. Also, the navbar should be shown when the user is on other pages. This hiding/showing applies only to the homepage.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementById("header-menu");
    window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
        element.classList.add("hidden");
    })
    window.onscroll = function() {hidemenu()};
    function hidemenu() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) {
        element.classList.remove("hidden");
      } else {
        element.classList.add("hidden");
      }
    }
</script>
```

This is how you can hide when page load
(or)
if you want to **hide in home page** and visible in other you can use

```
<body onload="hide-nav()">
....
</body> 

 <script>
var element = document.getElementById("header-menu");
        hide-nav=()=>{
        element.classList.add("hidden");
   }
        window.onscroll = function() {hidemenu()};
        function hidemenu() {
          if (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) {
            element.classList.remove("hidden");
          } else {
            element.classList.add("hidden");
          }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @ikmo! The first one works.. When I arrive at the (top of the) homepage, the navbar is hidden. However, the homepage is divided in sections, that lead to subpages. And I still encounter some problems here:   1) when I am on a subpage and I go to the top of the homepage. (so when clicking on the logo with <index#toppage">) , the navbar is visible during a microsecond. And then it disappears as it should. This looks a bit sloppy...

Comment: 2) Also, when I am on a subpage and I go back to the homepage, I arrive at the respective section part of the homepage (and not the top of the homepage). In this case, the navbar is not visible untill scrolled, which is not what I want...    In fact, the solution I am looking for is: I want the navbar visible the whole time, except when on less than 500px from the top of the homepage.

Comment: if u not comfortable with scroll try using **offset**  in java-script i think it will be useful